# How to import custom jinja2 filters from another file (and using Flask)?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a jinja_filters.py file with a few dozen custom filters I've written.  Now I have multiple Flask apps that need to use these filters.  (I'm not sure if my problem is Flask-specific or not.)

One hacky way to accomplish what I want is to do:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

import jinja_filters

@app.template_filter('filter_name1')
def filter_name1(arg):
    return jinja_filters.filter_name1(arg)

@app.template_filter('filter_name2')
def filter_name2(arg):
    return jinja_filters.filter_name2(arg)

...
```

What's the "right" way to do this?

EDIT: Ideally, I wouldn't have to list each filter name. So when I add a new filter to jinja_filters.py I don't have to update any other code -- all my apps would be able to use it right away.

Comment: famousgarkin's answer probably would have been the accepted answer, except for that two year gap.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Where ever you're setting up your app object (app.py, perhaps), you only need to import your custom filters and then modify the Jinja environment attribute.

```py
import jinja_filters

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.filters['filter_name1'] = jinja_filters.filter_name1
app.jinja_env.filters['filter_name2'] = jinja_filters.filter_name2
```

and so on.

Another possibility is to use the `inspect` module to find all the methods in `jinja_filters` like so:

```py
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import jinja_filters

app = Flask(__name__)

my_filters = {name: function 
                for name, function in getmembers(jinja_filters)
                if isfunction(function)}

app.jinja_env.filters.update(my_filters)
```

That code is untested, but the idea is to build a dictionary of function names and functions that exist in your `jinja_filters` files and then update the Jinja environment's filters dictionary with your filters.

Comment: That's definitely better than what I have.  But is there a way that I don't have to explicitly list each filter name?

Comment: I updated my answer with another solution that could dynamically add the filters using the `inspect` module.

Comment: Well, it gets the job done alright :)  But I still can't believe the authors of Jinja2/Flask didn't have a more succinct way to do this. (I'll checkmark your answer in a couple days if no one else chimes in.)

Comment: That seems pretty succinct to me. You could add hundreds of filters kept anywhere on the python path into the jinja environment in what is essentially two lines of code. I'd agree it might not be terribly obvious but I don't know that I could design a better way to do it.

Comment: I was hoping for something like a @global_register_filter decorator that I could use inside jinja_filters.py.  That way, all I'd have to do in my app is just "import jinja_filters" and that's it.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Sort of like how nose finds tests, flask might look for filters in files named a specific way and find methods in those files that are decorated as you suggest. That would be cool. It might be one of those things where it's a bit too much magic and not explicit enough.

Comment: @DustinBoswell See my answer for exactly that functionality, in case you will need it again sometime.

Comment: nice hack!  i like this

Answer (score 51):

There is a recommended way of doing this using [Flask blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/). One of it's use cases is this functionality specifically:

> - Provide template filters, static files, templates, and other utilities through blueprints. A blueprint does not have to implement applications or view functions.

You just need to create a [`flask.Blueprint`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#blueprint-objects) object and use it to register your filters in a similar way as you would with `flask.Flask` app object, using the [`Blueprint.app_template_filter`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.app_template_filter) decorator or [`Blueprint.add_app_template_filter`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.add_app_template_filter) method.

```
# filters.py

import jinja2
import flask

blueprint = flask.Blueprint('filters', __name__)

# using the decorator
@jinja2.contextfilter
@blueprint.app_template_filter()
def filter1(context, value):
    return 1

# using the method
@jinja2.contextfilter
def filter2(context, value):
    return 2

blueprint.add_app_template_filter(filter2)
```

Then you just need to register the blueprint on your app object:

```
# app.py

import flask
import filters

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(filters.blueprint)
```

And voilà, the filters are registered.

Comment: Its two years after the fact, and I'm nine years late to the party, but this is the better solution, the client has only to import the file and then one line to register the blueprint. I missed adding the "context" argument at first, but now I can filters and the client "app" code remains the same.

Comment: In Jinja 3.1 `contextfilter` is replaced by `pass_context`  https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/#version-3-1-0